# How to get variable value in array of buttons in android

Tags: android

```
for(i=1;i<=9;i++) {
        b[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                button_click(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

here, button_click is a user-defined function to which I want to send the value i(current number of a button) but when I execute it, all button gives value 10 to this function which is the value of I at the end of the loop. so how to solve this problem?

Comment: add a line `final int j = i;` before you set the OnClickListener and refer to this final variable instead of to i

Comment: @0x0nosugar It worked, thanks a lot.